# Change a shortcut's target using BAT script

Tags: batch-file

Actually, I want to take the copy of shortcut file and need to change the target.

For Copy, I have the scrip as below

```
xcopy /Y "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SFR.lnk" "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SFR-NEW.lnk"*
```

target is

**Currently:** "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\SFR\sfr.exe".

Here I want to change the target after take copy and I tried some thing, but it does not work.

```
xcopy /Y "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SFR.lnk" "C:\Users\799964\Desktop\SFR-NEW.lnk"*
ChangeLNKs    /p=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\SFR\sfr.exe -admin
```

I need only bat script to change the target after copy of short cut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears from your provided code, that you do not need to edit the target at all. You are only appending an argument, so it would be more sensible to just add an argument.

You have already been advised that other languages can do what you need, but in order to remain on topic, I've provided two complete batch files which utilise them.

One using [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell):

```bat
@FindStr /V "^@" "%~f0"|PowerShell -&GoTo :EOF
$SrcePath = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SFR.lnk'
$DestPath = 'C:\Users\799964\Desktop\SFR-NEW.lnk'
Copy-Item $SrcePath $DestPath
$Shortcut = (New-Object -COM WScript.Shell).CreateShortcut($DestPath)
$Shortcut.Arguments = '-admin'
$Shortcut.Save()
```

And one using [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript):

```bat
::'@CScript //NoLogo //E:VBScript "%~f0"&Exit /B
SrcePath = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SFR.lnk"
DestPath = "C:\Users\799964\Desktop\SFR-NEW.lnk"
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CopyFile SrcePath,DestPath
Set Shortcut = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CreateShortcut(DestPath)
Shortcut.Arguments = "-admin"
Shortcut.Save
Set Shortcut = Nothing
```

In this example there's an invisible third character <kbd>SUB</kbd>, *(0x1A)*, which should copy fine, but is worth mentioning regardless.

Choose one or the other, *in terms of speed, I'd probably choose the latter*.